# Rust String::to_bytes | What does the Rust compiler mean here, exactly?

Tags: rust

I am newbie in the Rust world.

As an exercise, this is the problem I am trying to solve:

```
fn main() {
    let s = give_ownership();
    println!("{}", s);
}

// Only modify the code below!
fn give_ownership() -> String {
    let s = String::from("hello, world");
    // Convert String to Vec
    let _s = s.into_bytes();
    s
}
```

I have gotten through. My solution works.

However, when I compile the exercise code-snippet above unchanged, I don't quite get what the compiler is telling me here, as a *note* below:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `s`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
9  |     let s = String::from("hello, world");
   |         - move occurs because `s` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
10 |     // Convert String to Vec
11 |     let _s = s.into_bytes();
   |                ------------ `s` moved due to this method call
12 |     s
   |     ^ value used here after move
   |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `s`
```

My guess is that the note is about the function *into_bytes()*. The RustDoc says this about the function:

> This consumes the String, so we do not need to copy its contents.

Could someone please elaborate on this?

Comment: Hm, not really sure what is there to elaborate, `into_bytes` takes ownership of the string and destroys it. You can't use `s` after that. If you want to keep using `s`, destroy a clone, `s.clone().into_bytes()`

Comment: There is [`str::as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes) which takes a reference and not ownership of the `String`, so you can use it to create your `Vec`

Comment: @hellow: good point. Although they'd still have to copy that data in order to return a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`into_bytes()` takes `self` (i.e. an owned self, not a reference).

This means that it takes ownership of the string it's called on. It's conceptually the same as this:

```rust
fn main() {
  let s = String::from("hello");
  take_string(s);
  println!("{s}");  // ERROR
}

fn take_string(s: String) {}
```

This is useful because it allows you to turn a `String` into a `Vec<u8>`, while reusing the allocation. A `String` is really just a `Vec<u8>` with the guarantee that the bytes are valid UTF-8.

So once you write `let _s = s.into_bytes()`, the data that was in `s` has now moved to `_s`, so you can't return `s` from your function. There's *nothing there*.

If you just want to return the string, you can just return `String::from("stuff")`

Comment: "There's nothing there" - conceptually, yes. Physically, the memory is not cleared, of course.

Comment: I'd argue that whether the memory is cleared is an implementation detail. The Rust abstract machine expects moves to be destructive bitwise copies. Even in the compiler, a "moved-out-of" variable is treated basically identically to a "not-yet initialized" variable like `let x;`

Comment: Sounds fair enough.

Comment: Sincere apologies for late reply. Thank you, @cameron1024 for a detailed answer. The term _consumes_ baffled me a bit but now its usage and semantics are much clearer.

Comment: SOF doesn't allow me to mention more than one for reasons unknown to me. So, here is thanking @sergio-tulentsev for sharing the line of thought. As a newbie, as much as the answer, I also want to be benefited by how experts think.

Comment: SOF doesn't allow me to mention more than one for reasons unknown to me. So, here is thanking @hellow for sharing the line of thought. As a newbie, as much as the answer, I also want to be benefited by how experts think.